# Close all open elements

Tags: meteor

I'm using reactive-var, currently the event below shows and hides the hidden div when it is clicked. Since there are a number of options I would like to change the event below to hide any of the open divs and only display the one I've clicked on. How would I write that?

Path: `templates.html`

```
    <template name="jobOfferLayout">
        {{#each jobOffers}}

        {{> jobOfferCard}}

        {{/each}}   
    </template>

<template name="jobOfferCard">

    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item smallInfo">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{jobs}}</h4>
        </a>
    </div>

    {{#if showFullContent}}
        <div class="bigInfo">
         Show big info
        </div>

    {{/if}}

</template>
```

Path: `jobOfferCard.js`

```
Template.jobOfferCard.onCreated(function(){
  this.showFullContent = new ReactiveVar(false);
});


Template.jobOfferCard.helpers({
    showFullContent: function(){
        return Template.instance().showFullContent.get();
    },
});

Template.jobOfferCard.events({
  "click .smallInfo": function(event, template){
    template.showFullContent.set(!template.showFullContent.get());  
  },
});
```

Comment: you can use a helper function and use blaze to display/hide

Comment: can you please provide more detail what actually you want to do ?

Comment: Ok I've included more info above. There is  a list of jobs, each job has a job card. Currently when you click on a job it opens the card that it is linked to. The problem I'm having is if you click on multiple jobs you end up having multiple cards open. I want the cards to close when a new job is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your job offer cards have a unique id like `_id`, then you can save the id inside the `ReactiveVar` instead of saving `true` or `false` like this,

```
Template.jobOfferCard.onCreated(function(){
     this.showFullContent = new ReactiveVar(false);
});


Template.jobOfferCard.helpers({
    showFullContent: function(){
         return Template.instance().showFullContent.get() === this._id;
    },
});

Template.jobOfferCard.events({
    "click .smallInfo": function(event, template){
        template.showFullContent.set(this._id);
    },
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
Template.jobOfferCard.onCreated(function(){
    Session.setDefault('job-offer-card-opened', false); 
});


Template.jobOfferCard.helpers({
    showFullContent: function(){
        return Session.get('job-offer-card-opened') === this._id;
    },
});

Template.jobOfferCard.events({
    "click .smallInfo": function(event, template){
        Session.set('job-offer-card-opened', this._id);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tired this but it doesn't appear to close the jobcards that are open. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bp123 Do you have `_id` for each `jobOfferCard`? Can you put a `console.log(this._id)` in `showFullContent` helper and in `click .smallInfo` event and let me know what both of them return.

Comment: YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 and Sa69oM9vw73o2t6Wg

Comment: @bp123 Strange! console.log in `showFullContent` should log as many `jobOfferCards` on the page, but looks like it logged it only one time. If there are more than one items and if it logged only one time then there must be an error or something? But I can say that the approach is this. You need to find out why it is returning different results for `this._id` in helper and event.

Comment: sorry that was my fault it says YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8

Comment: @bp123 It should work then. Remove console.log in your click event and change your console.log in helper to `console.log(Template.instance().showFullContent.get(), this._id)`. Does it console log as many times as the number of job offer cards? For example, if you have two items YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 and Sa69oM9vw73o2t6Wg, and if you click on jobOfferCard for YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8, it should print 2 times, one should be `YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8` and 2nd one should be `YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 Sa69oM9vw73o2t6Wg`.

Comment: when i load the page it says false "YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8" false "Sa69oM9vw73o2t6Wg" and then when i click one it says YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8 YB2YRGwtdc5YsRZr8

Comment: @bp123 Oh I see. I understand it now, since each jobOfferCard has different template, each template has a separate `ReactiveVar` and it is not working. I would suggest you use Session variable instead of reactive var to solve your problem. See updated answer.